# Magento GET Array Empty At Model

Tags: error, ajax

Where to begin? An AJAX call is made to the Index controller action like so:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",encodeURI(ctrlPath)+'?pId='+encodeURIComponent(pId)+'&pName='+encodeURIComponent(pName)+'&pUrl='+encodeURIComponent(pUrl)+'&email='+encodeURIComponent(cliendEmailId),true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
```

The controller Index action contains:

```
public function storeNotificationProductDataAction()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $notifySuccessMes =  Mage::getStoreConfig('Outofstocknotification/general/activate_apptha_outofstock_notify_success_mes');
    $statusOfInsert = Mage::getModel('outofstocknotification/outofstocknotification')->notifyDataInserted();
    $statusOfInsert = intval($statusOfInsert);

    if ($statusOfInsert) {
        echo $notifySuccessMes;
    } else {
        echo "okay";
    }
}
```

The getModel() above calls the following model:

```
public function notifyDataInserted() {
    $isArray = count($_GET);
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $read = $resource->getConnection('write');

    var_dump($_GET);

    $tPrefix = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
    $stockNotifiTable = $tPrefix . 'outofstocknotification';

    $this->getTable('outofstocknotification');
    if ($isArray) {
        ...blah blah blah db stuff
    }
}
```

The var_dump() retuns an empty array: `array(0) { }`. The AJAX calls fails with `canceled` but a direct call to the URL results in `okay`.

So, the GET variable is empty in the model. Please tell me why?

Also, this is NOT my code, please don't hate :)

Comment: Instead of `$_GET` try to use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()`.

Comment: Thx Marius, I switched to that but no dice. Good practice tho :)

Comment: What is the value of ```ctrlPath``` in the Ajax request code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, And so, so simple in the end. The URL definition (ctrlPath) was defined as insecure:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB) . 'outofstocknotification/index/storeNotificationProductData';
```

Instead I switched to secure, like this:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL)
```

And it works wonderfully! Thanks to Vinai for the pointer! :) Now to tidy up this horrible code!

Comment: Try using ```Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('outofstocknotification/index/storeNotificationProductData', array('_secure' => true))``` instead (a bit cleaner)